# Assigning *mut to a LocalKey

Tags: rust

```
use std::thread;
use std::ptr::null_mut;

struct Foo;

thread_local!(static F: *mut Foo = std::ptr::null_mut());

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo;
    F.with(|f|{
        f = std::ptr::null_mut();
        //f = foo as *mut Foo;
    });
}
```

```
src/main.rs:234:13: 234:33 error: mismatched types [E0308]
src/main.rs:234         f = std::ptr::null_mut();
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:234:13: 234:33 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:234:13: 234:33 note: expected type `&*mut Foo`
src/main.rs:234:13: 234:33 note:    found type `*mut _`
```

`with` is defined as

```
fn with<F, R>(&'static self, f: F) -> R 
where F: FnOnce(&T) -> R
```

How would I assign a new `*mut` to `f` inside `with`?

```
use std::thread;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use std::cell::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo{
    i: i32
}

thread_local!(static F: Cell<*mut Foo> = Cell::new(std::ptr::null_mut()));

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo{i : 42};
    let foop = &mut foo as *mut Foo;
    F.with(|f|{
        let mut f1 = f.get();
        println!("{:?}", f1);
        f1 = foop;
    });
    F.with(|f|{
        println!("{:?}", f.get());
    });
}
```

I am now using a `Cell` to get around the compile error but the problem is that the following prints:

```
0x0
0x0
```

Which means that I am not assigning a new mutable pointer to the thread local variable `F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Cell` (similar to the [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html#examples)):

```
use std::ptr;
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Foo;

thread_local!(static F: Cell<*mut Foo> = Cell::new(ptr::null_mut()));

fn main() {
    // let mut foo = Foo;
    F.with(|f| {
        f.set(ptr::null_mut());
        // Don't do this, you can generate a use after free if foo is dropped
        // f.set(&mut foo);
    });
}
```

In the examples `RefCell` is used, but as `*mut` implements `Copy`, using `Cell` is [sufficient](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html).

Comment: Isn't a `Cell` sufficient since pointers are `Copy` (although you have to use `set`). A `RefCell` introduces run-time checking which seems unnecessary here.